# Is credit/debit card's chip programming clone to another empty chip card

Tags: credit-card

Card's magnetic strip and chip should programmed by banking system. Is there any chance to clone same programming to another chip and magnetic strip empty card?

By doing this, our cards may be cloned or not?  If vendor and person with a cloned card can do transactions together with mutual understanding?

Comment: What do you mean by your last sentence? You tagged this with "email"; why did you tag it that way?

Comment: @schroeder, I would interpret the "with mutual understanding" as the vendor and person who cloned the card working together, both knowing that they're committing fraud.  (In which case, I'd ask Naresh why the vendor and the card cloner need to be different people?)

Comment: @Ghedipunk ah, ok. I'm not sure how that's relevant to the core question, though.